# KendoUI Grid serverpaging

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I'm trying to populate a KendoUI grid with JSON data where the server returns the total number of rows along with the data, but I'm having some trouble getting serverPaging to work properly. I create and assign the dataSource of the grid as follows:

```
                var oDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    schema: {
                        data:  "data",
                        total: "total"
                    },
                    data: self.grdTableData,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    pageSise: 50,
                    total: joOutput["TotalRecords"]
                });

                grdTableResults.setDataSource(oDS);
```

and the first page shows the first 50 of 939 records but there is only ever 1 page (the navigation arrows never respond to anything) and I see NaN - NaN of 939 items and the rotating circle of dots in the centre of the grid that never goes away.

One thing that is different in all the examples I've looked at is that my $.ajax call and the the processing of the JSON data  in .done doesn't use "transport: read" but I'm thinking how I send the data and get it back shouldn't matter (or does it because every page request is a new server read?). But I don't think I'm doing enough to handle the server paging properly even though it seems I'm setting data source values similar to those set in the example at http://jsfiddle.net/rusev/Lnkug/. Then there's the "take" and "skip" values that I'm not sure about, but I do have "startIndex" and "rowsPerPage" that I'm sending to the server that can be used there. I assume the grid can tell me what page I'm on show I can set my "startIndex" appropriately and if I have an Items per Page" drop down I can reset my "rowsPerPage" value?

Anyway, sorry for all the newbie questions. Any help and suggestions is genuinely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are few questions that I do not understand: You mention server paging but it actually seems to me that your data comes from a JavaScript array called `self.grdTableData` if so, it doesn't make sense saying `serverPaging`, this is for remote servers.

Comment: There is a typo error in `pageSize` where you wrote `pageSise`, is it also in the code?

Comment: Why do you define a `schema`? It doesn't seem that you need it keeping in mind the actual definition.

Comment: While the client and the server are the same machine now for testing purposes, eventually the server will be remote. Perhaps I'm not understanding if serverPaging is really necessary--the data is still a JavaScript array no matter where it comes from. I guess I'm just needing a mechanism to read blocks of data so that I can read and page data data more efficiently that having potentially thousands of  rows of data.

Comment: That was indeed a typo, which got rid of the rotating circles and now I see multple page numbers and 1 - 50 of 939 items instead of NaN - NaN of 939 items, but still no response from clicking on any numbers or arrows. Thanks for caching that.

Comment: I thought I needed the schema to pass in the total records back to the client so that the grid and other client code I still might need to write to facilitate proper paging. Perhaps I don't need to go quite that far?

Again, thanks for all your help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: About `serverPaging`, it is used when you want to transfer from a web server parts of data from the total **and** the server is able to generate this parts and able as well to understand which part are you willing to receive. There is a _protocol_ for communicating the server and the client (browser). If you are getting the data from a JavaScript array (i.e. the data is already in the browser) does not make sense talking about `serverPaging` and I would expect some strange behavior. If you post some running code in JSFiddle or JSBin I can take a look into.

Comment: The server is able to do that if it is passed the correct page number from the grid and how many rows are are each page (50). What I really need is a way to know what page I'm on so that I can use that with the number of rows per page to get new data. This would be done via an ajax call to the server which fills the JavaScript array with JSON data in response to a page click event, thus satisfying the server communication protocol. I've never used JSFiddle or JSBin, so I couldn't be of any help to you there. :(

I also spoke to soon, I still see the rotating circles. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**transport: read**

You should be able to use "transport: read" even if you have custom logic by setting the value to a function. I have created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/empie/9sctL/) to demonstrate this functionality.

```
dataSource: {
    serverPaging: true,
    schema: {
        data: "data",
        total: "total"
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    transport: {
        read: function(options) {
            var data = getData(options.data.page);
            options.success(data);
        }
    },
    update: function() {}
}
```

Your read function contains a parameter that contains the following paging properties: page, pageSize, skip, take. Keep in mind that all transport operations need to be functions if one operation contains a function.

**startIndex and rowsPerPage**

If your server accepts these parameters, you should be able to submit them in the read function. Create a new ajax call that post customized data

```
var ajaxPostData = { startIndex: options.data.skip, rowsPerPage: options.data.pageSize }
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I want to do it with server side wrapper (asp.net mvc), do you know if it is possible ?

Comment: @Ashkan Can you please share the ASP.Net wrapper approach for this, if you have a solution?

Comment: @Lijo: I posted as an answer, hopefully it may be helpful for the others.

Comment: @emp Thanks so much for this.  Do you know if the `take`, `skip`, `keep`, `page` and `pageSize` parameters are documented anywhere?

Comment: No I'm afraid they aren't documented (they are not here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid). You just need to use Fiddler or any other network inspector to view the request. The params are self explanatory...

Comment: You're the man.. I've been trying to figure this out for a bit now and the schema setup of data/total were what I was missing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**This is the code for server side wrapper** that I'm using to implement server paging with kendo grid:

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<IJRayka.Core.Utility.ViewModels.ProductDto>()
.Name("productList")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(prod => prod.Name);
    columns.Bound(ord => ord.Brand);
    columns.Bound(ord => ord.UnitPackageOption);
    columns.Bound(ord => ord.CategoryName);
    columns.Bound(ord => ord.Description);
})
.Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(true))
.Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
.PrefixUrlParameters(false)
.DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
            .Model(m => m.Id(ord => ord.ID))
            .PageSize(5)
            .Read(read => read
                .Action("FilterProductsJson", "ProductManagement")
                .Data("getFilters"))
            )
)
```

Where `getFilters` is a **javascript function** that passes my custom filter parameters to the grid when it wants to get data from url/service:

```js
function getFilters() {
    return {
        brand: $("#Brand").val(),
        name: $("#Name").val(),
        category: $("#CategoryName").val()
    };
}
```

In addition you should implement your controller's action method using kendo's `DataSourceRequest` class like below, or otherwise it won't work the way you want:

```cs
public JsonResult FilterProductsJson([DataSourceRequest()] DataSourceRequest request,
                                // three additional paramerters for my custom filtering
                                string brand, string name, string category)
{
    int top = request.PageSize;
    int skip = (request.Page - 1) * top;
    if(brand != null)
        brand = brand.Trim();
    if(name != null)
        name = name.Trim();
    if(category != null)
        category = category.Trim();

    var searchResult = new ManageProductBiz().GetPagedFilteredProducts(brand, name, category, top, skip);
    // remove cyclic references:
    searchResult.Items.ForEach(prd => prd.Category.Products = null);

    return Json(new DataSourceResult { Data = searchResult.Items, Total = searchResult.TotalCount }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the page numbers are not coming correct here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064144/custom-ajax-binding-does-not-work-properly?